# Create Custom layout module

Tags: magento-1.9, module, layout, controllers, frontend

Hi i just created custom module in magento and its frontend doesn't work.

The config file :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
<modules>
    <Shareino_Sync>
        <version>0.1.0</version>
    </Shareino_Sync>
</modules>

<global>
     <helpers>
        <sync>
            <class>Shareino_Sync_Helper</class>
        </sync>
    </helpers>
    <blocks>
        <sync>
            <class>Shareino_Sync_Block</class>
        </sync>
    </blocks>
</global>
<frontend>
    <routers>
        <sync>
            <use>standard</use>
            <args>
                <module>Shareino_Sync</module>
                <frontName>sync</frontName>
            </args>
        </sync>
    </routers>
    <layout>
        <updates>
            <sync>
                <file>shareino_front.xml</file>
            </sync>
        </updates>
    </layout>
</frontend>

</config>
```

The layout file  :

```
# File in : app/design/frontend/default/default/layout/shareino_front.xml
<layout version="0.1.0">
    <sync_index_index>
        <reference name="content">
            <block type="sync/sync" name="sync" template="sync_index.phtml" />
        </reference>
    </sync_index_index>
</layout>
```

And `sync_index.phtml` :

```
# file in app/design/frontend/default/default/template/sync_index.phtml
<h1>
    Test Text
</h1>
```

I created a block that named `Sync.php`

```
class Shareino_Sync_Block_Sync extends Mage_Core_Block_Template
{
    public function myfunction()
    {
        return "Hello tuts+ world";
    }
}
```

At the end my controller  :

```
class Shareino_Sync_IndexController extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action
{
    public function indexAction(){

            $this->loadLayout();


            $this->renderLayout();

    }
    public function testAction(){
        echo "index Action";
    }
}
```

I think i done every think well , but when i load the action url in browser it doesn't my layout. please help me to know my wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that your front route does not match your layout and controllers.

You need to replace the following:

```
 <frontName>shareinosync</frontName>
```

With:

```
 <frontName>sync</frontName>
```

Comment: i change it but steel it doesn't work

Comment: @SaeedDarvish what URL are you trying to access ?

Comment: Before change shareinosync to  sync i opened 
http://mg1.dev/index.php/shareinosync/index
but now i open http://mg1.dev/index.php/sync/index but there is not any difference , its load default layout but it doesn't put my content in it

Comment: @SaeedDarvish what if you move your layout file from default/default to base/default ?

Comment: why? its worked ... thanks  a lote

Comment: @SaeedDarvish you should always put your module layout files AND template files under base/default the reason is because the fallback theme mechanism of Magento first look for those files in your_package/your_theme then under your_package/default then under base/default. So if you put those files under default/default and your package is not default those files will never be found

Comment: @SaeedDarvish feel free to mark your question as answered so it will benefit for others ;)

Answer (score 1):

Saneed, i have an issue with block class.

You have define block type prefix is  in `config.xml` .

```
<blocks>
        <mymodule> <!- this call block  -->
            <class>Shareino_Sync_Block</class>
        </mymodule>
    </blocks>
```

So,you need to change block type prefix to **sync**. As because of you call a block type prefix as **sync** `(<block type="sync/sync")` at layout code

Comment: Your're right ,but steel it doesn't work

Answer (score 1):

you should always put your module layout files AND template files under base/default the reason is because the fallback theme mechanism of Magento first look for those files in your_package/your_theme then under your_package/default then under base/default. So if you put those files under default/default and your package is not default those files will never be found

Comment: That's right but did you copy this text from answers?